# How to expand this taylor series and find radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

f(x)= √(1-x) at x=0

How do you find the taylor series and radius of convergence?

Comment: Write this as $(1-x)^{1/2}$ and differentiate it two or three times (don't forget the Chain Rule!).  You should see a pattern appear so that you can write what the general term for the $n^{th}$ derivative, $f^{(n)}(0)$.  You will also need that in order to write the test ratio for finding the radius of convergence using the Ratio Test.

Answer (score 3):

$$(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-1)(\frac{1}{2}-2)\cdots(\frac{1}{2}-k+1)}{k!}x^k$$
and
\begin{align}\frac{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-1)(\frac{1}{2}-2)\cdots(\frac{1}{2}-k+1)}{k!}&=\frac{(-1)(-3)\cdots(3-2k)}{2^kk!}=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1\times3\times\cdots\times(2k-3)}{2^kk!}\\&=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(2k-2)!}{2^{2k-1}k!(k-1)!}\end{align}
hence we have
$$(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k-2)!}{2^{2k-1}k!(k-1)!}x^k=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k$$

Finaly by the D'Alembert criterion we have
$$\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2k(2k+1)}{2^2(k+1)k}=1$$